Why does Eclipse show "Push HEAD" button after I did "Commit and Push" (to small Gitlab)
We have a small Gitlab setup for one of our development environments, and I am using Eclipse and when I make changes to a file, I move the file from Unstaged changes to Staged Changes and add a Commit Message.
Eclipse has 2 buttons, "Commit and Push" and "Commit", and I've been pressing the "Commit and Push" button and then Eclipse shows the popup for success, but Eclipse then shows a "Push HEAD" button, and from what I can tell the updated file is making it into Gitlab successfully.
Why is Eclipse showing the "Push HEAD" button, and, also, should I/do I need to push the "Push HEAD" button?
Thanks,
Jim

To be precise, the button is not called Push HEAD, but Push HEAD..., and the suffix ... indicates that pressing the button does not directly execute a command but opens a dialog that provides options like e.g. for force pushing or for pushing your local HEAD to a new remote.
In your case, with a single upstream remote, you only need Push HEAD... to do a force push (when doing Commit and Push, only the commit may succeed, but the push may be rejected by the server, e.g. with the reason non-fast-forward) or if you want to push your local commits that you have not already pushed individually via Commit and Push, e.g. when working offline or when you did a revert commit (in the History view you can right-click a commit and choose Revert Commit which creates locally an inverse commit which you then want to push via Push HEAD...).

howlger - thanks for the response.  You are correct, the button says "Push HEAD...".  So I was looking at the 'non-fast-forward' link in you response and in one of the posts there it mentions running 'gitk --all' so I tried that, and at the top it says "local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index" - so should I use the Push HEAD... to do a force push?  FYI, when I do a pull right now from a different machine that has Eclipse, I do ALREADY see the latest change, so do I even need to do the force push?  Sorry for the questions :(

A force push replaces what is on remote: it deletes the commits that have been done by other after your last pull and may cause problems for those who pulled commits that were overwritten/deleted by your force push. Therefore, use it with caution, especially if you not the only one working on this remote repo. In most cases of non-fast-forward, you want to rebase or merge your local commits to be able to push them. Many prefer rebase over merge since a rebase gives you a linear history which is easier to read than a non-linear history with some commits having more than one parent commit.

When you do Git commands on the command line, then you need do hit to the Refresh (F5) button in the Git Staging view (EGit uses JGit which is a Git implementation in Java; it does not delegate to the command line).

howlger Thanks! - I've marked your answer.
